# How to change CSS dynamically for whole site with vite and lit?

Tags: css, node.js, vite, lit

Dear all I am developing a node app with vite and lit. I like to have the option that the user can change the style dynamically at runtime for instance to select between a dark and bright theme for the whole site.

I know that you can directly `import` "css" files and apply it on single lit elements. But how I can change the style dynamically for the whole site? I also noticed that an `ìmport from "xxxx.css"` can not contain a dynamic variable,so the following seems not to be supported?

```
let theme = "dark"
import "folder/" + theme + ".css";
```

Any suggestion how I can best achieve my goal?

Comment: You can't style shadowDOM with global CSS (that is the whole point of shadowDOM). Inheritable styles like color, fonts and CSS properties do style shadowRoots. So if you want to style everything with global CSS, then do not use shadowDOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best handled by setting all your colors in your elements as CSS Custom Properties. e.g.

```
class MyCustomCard extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`
    .card {
      /* Set custom property and default value */
      background-color: var(--sys-color-surface, #FFF);
      color: var(--sys-color-on-surface, #000);
      ...
    }
  `;
  ...
}
```

Then you can have a theming.css file at the root of your document. e.g.

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css">
</head>
```

```css
/* theme.css */
/* light theme */
:root, body.force-light-mode {
  --sys-color-surface: #FFF;
  --sys-color-on-surface: #000;
  ...
}
/* auto dark theme */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --sys-color-surface: #000;
    --sys-color-on-surface: #FFF;
    ...
  }
}

/* user preference dark mode */
body.force-dark-mode {
  /* This can be deduplicated with an @import https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import */
  --sys-color-surface: #000;
  --sys-color-on-surface: #FFF;
  ...
}
```

Then you can have a dark theme toggle that toggles the `force-*-mode` class on body:

```
class ThemeToggle extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html`
      <div>Select Theme</div>
      <label>
        Light Mode
        <input
            type="radio"
            @change=${this.onChange('light')}
            name="theme">
       </label>
      <label>
        Follow System
        <input
            type="radio"
            @change=${this.onChange('system')}
            name="theme"
            checked>
       </label>
      <label>
        Dark Mode
        <input
            type="radio"
            @change=${this.onChange('dark')}
            name="theme">
       </label>`
  }

  onChange = (mode) => (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      switch(mode) {
        case 'light':
          document.body.classList.add('force-light-mode');
          break;
        case 'dark':
          document.body.classList.add('force-dark-mode');
          break;
      }
    } else {
      switch(mode) {
        case 'light':
          document.body.classList.remove('force-light-mode');
          break;
        case 'dark':
          document.body.classList.remove('force-dark-mode');
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```